# resource plugin error when upgrading from grails 2.3.8 2.4

Tags: grails

Im following the [docs](http://www.grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom23.html) trying to upgrade my project from 2.3.8 to 2.4, but I am encountering these error(s)

```
localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceProcessor  - Unable to load resources
Message: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.getGrailsPlugin() is applicable    
for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [lesscss-resources]


->>    5 | run                   in BootstrapResources
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     46 | doCall                in org.grails.plugin.resource.module.ModuleDeclarationsFactory$_getModuleDeclarations_closure2
|     41 | getModuleDeclarations in org.grails.plugin.resource.module.ModuleDeclarationsFactory
|    715 | loadModules           in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor
|   1013 | reloadAll . . . . . . in     ''
|    166 | doCall                in ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker             in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                   in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2014-06-03 13:38:16,282 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [localhost].   [/DocumentManagementSystem]  - Exception starting filter sitemesh
Message: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter
Line | Method
->>   59 | findClass in org.grails.plugins.tomcat.ParentDelegatingClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    358 | loadClass in     ''
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2014-06-03 13:38:16,300 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Error     filterStart
Error |
```

Does this sound like a plugin issue? Or something I might have skipped over in the documentation

Here is my buildconfig plugin section

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat8:8.0.5"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.0"
    compile ':cache:1.1.6'
//      compile ":mail:1.0.5"
//      compile ":ckeditor:4.4.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    compile ":searchable:0.6.7"
    compile ":jquery:1.11.1"
//      compile ":shiro:1.2.1"
//      compile ":resources:1.2.8"
    compile ':asset-pipeline:1.8.3'
//      compile (":nimble:0.7"){
//          
//          exclude "servlet-api"
//          
//          }

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.15" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.5.1"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.8"
```

New sitemesh error

```
Error |
2014-06-03 14:41:32,304 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [localhost].[/DocumentManagementSystem]  - Exception starting filter sitemesh
Message: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter
Line | Method
->>   61 | findClass in org.grails.plugins.tomcat.ParentDelegatingClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    358 | loadClass in     ''
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
```

Comment: Which version of `resources` plugin is used?

Comment: If you are using the twitter bootstrap plugin and upgrade it to 3.1.1.3. Refer [this issue](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/issues/107) and this [commit](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/commit/fbbeabbb922cd3d95375882e7eccf84720ffe85b). Assuming you are using latest version 1.2.8 of resources plugin.

Comment: 1.2.8 was being used. I have resolved this issue, updated tomcat to 8.8.0.5 and removed use of some plugins temporarily, but am now getting 'Error executing script RunApp: java.lang.NullPointerException'

Comment: Can you add plugin section of `BuildConfig.groovy` in the question?

Comment: Edited into the original post. I'm probably going to remove the nimble plugin completely and switch over to the Spring Security plugin as I move further along in my project, but otherwise I use most of these

Comment: Reason for upgrading tomcat, can you get back to `7.0.42`? You can remove asset-pipeline if you want to use resources. But again as stated in the answer, henceforth asset-pipeline is the default resource management plugin for Grails.

Comment: I upgraded tomcat as I was getting another error relating to it, which is now edited into the post. This error has reappared. Is this related to the web.xml changes document in 2.4?

Comment: There can be many open items effecting this behavior. Can you share a project in github?

Answer (score 7):

Your web.xml may still contain references to the sitemesh filter:

> http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/guide/upgradingFrom23.html
>
> > The Sitemesh servlet filter has been removed and the GSP layout feature is now handled by GrailsLayoutView.

Rename the src/templates folder to src/templates-old, then run grails install-templates. If you previously customised your web.xml, you will need to edit the generated web.xml to make these changes again.

Answer (score 2):

As it says in documentation no longer you need to use resource plugin:

> ```
> As of Grails 2.4 the resources plugin has been replaced with the asset-pipeline
> ```

now you could use asset plugin instead.
use this [link](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.0.M1/guide/single.html#resources) and you can easily upgrade your resources from 2.3.8 to 2.4.

Comment: Wrong interpretation. For a new Grails app with version 2.4.0 you get asset-pipeline by default. That does not mean if you are using resources plugin in 2.3.8, you cannot use it any more in 2.4.0.

Comment: @dmahapatro I know, and I didn't say that you cant use resource! I said "no longer you need to use resource plugin" and "you could use asset plugin instead". I think when you can easily use assets why bother and try to upgrade in a way that you could still use resource. read my answer more carefully!

Comment: That does not address the issue directly what OP is facing, it is a suggestion, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in the jQuery-ui plugin in `JqueryUiPluginResources.groovy` in the following two lines:

```
def appCtx = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext

def plugin = appCtx.pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin('jquery-ui')
```

The fix for this is present in the following commit: https://github.com/gpc/grails-jquery-ui/pull/13