# Grails 2.4 ClassNotFoundException: Sitemesh GrailsPageFilter

Tags: grails, classnotfoundexception, sitemesh

**Please note**: This question is *almost* a duplicate to [this one titled "resource plugin error when upgrading from grails 2.3.8 2.4"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021641/resource-plugin-error-when-upgrading-from-grails-2-3-8-2-4), however a few things are different that, in my mind, make it worthy of asking it as a separate question:

- In that question, neither the question nor any answers explain *why* this error is occurring, other than stating that the plugin being used was no longer the official Grails plugin for loading sitemesh
- **MOST IMPORTANTLY:** In that question, there was never an accepted answer or any verification from the original poster about what the final solution was. I won't do that.

So, I ask that before you down/closevote this as a dupe, to please point out to me where in that other question the *exact* solution was provided that will also apply to my *exact* situation. **If you can't do that, please don't down/closevote this question!**

I am upgrading a Grails 2.3.6 app to Grails 2.4.4. When I do a `run-app` I get:

```
Error |
2015-03-05 14:42:44,257 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [localhost].[/myapp]  - Exception starting filter sitemesh
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter
    at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.ParentDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(ParentDelegatingClassLoader.java:59)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5485)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Error |
2015-03-05 14:42:44,268 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Error filterStart
Error |
2015-03-05 14:42:44,270 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Context [/myapp] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Here's my `BuildConfig`'s plugins section:

```
plugins {
    runtime ":resources:1.2.14"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:gson:1.1.4'
    compile ":standalone:1.3"
    build ":release:3.0.1"
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    compile ":cache-headers:1.1.7"
    compile ":yammer-metrics:3.0.1-2"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.8" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.1.1"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    test(":geb:$gebVersion")
    test(":spock:0.7") {
        exclude "spock-grails-support"
    }
}
```

I do **not** want to use `asset-pipeline` if it can be avoided. Everything I've read so far states that using `resources:1.2.14` makes a Grails 2.4.4 app compatible with the resources plugin.

Can someone explain the Grails 2.4.4 way of using sitemesh so that this error goes away? If using `asset-pipeline` is unavoidable, what are the exact conversions I would need to make to my project to use it. I did try replacing the resource plugin with the latest asset pipeline plugin like so:

```
plugins {
    ...
    //runtime ":resources:1.2.14"
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.3"
    ...
}
```

But the error didn't go away. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to use the resources plugin in Grails 2.4.4, but my recommendation would be to use the `asset-pipeline`, as it is far superior to the older `resources` plugin. Here is a very good article explaining why (from the author of the plugin), and how:

- [Why asset pipeline over Grails resources plugin?](https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/wiki/Why-asset-pipeline-over-grails-resources-plugin)

### Edit

On second look, I believe this may be an issue with an incompatible `web.xml` from version 2.3.x. which had the following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Here is a link to the new 2.4.x `web.xml` file:

- https://gist.github.com/caseyscarborough/03b06f1cd7c2ff331c5a

Comment: What is solutions for Grails 4.X? Because Grails 4.x.x hasn't  web.xml  file.. @blacktide

Answer (score 0):

If you are here with Grails 4.x, take a look at your **sitemesh.xml** file.

In my case, the file was uneccessary after the Grails upgrade, so I deleted src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml to use the defaults. You will obviously want to keep a backup of this file until you know if you can solve the problem in the same way with your project.