# GrailsPageFilter is not Importing -Grails 4.x.x

Tags: grails, groovy

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter
```

[image]

This library has imported and worked fine on Grails 2.x.x but when I am trying to Import it on Grails 4.x
it is not importing!

How can I import is on Grails 4.x.x? Or need a solution.

Currently using this Dependency :

```
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-dateutil', version: '2.5.0'
```

**Codes:**

```
def buttonDropDown = { attrs, body ->
        def id = attrs.id
        def r = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceTagLib')
        r.require(module: "jquery-ui")


        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append('<button ')
                .append('id="' + id + '">')
                .append(body).append('</button>')
        StringBuilder jsbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        jsbuilder.append(' <script type="text/javascript">')
                .append(' $(document).ready(function(){')
                .append(' $("#' + id + '").button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-locked"},text: true);')
                .append(' });')
                .append('</script>')

        def headerWriter = getHeaderWriter()
        headerWriter << jsbuilder
        out << builder.toString()

    }

    private getHeaderWriter() {
        def gspSitemeshPage = request[GrailsPageFilter.GSP_SITEMESH_PAGE]
        def headBuffer = gspSitemeshPage.metaClass.getProperty(gspSitemeshPage, 'headBuffer')
        return headBuffer.writer
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887118/grails-2-4-classnotfoundexception-sitemesh-grailspagefilter

Comment: This issue for Grails 2.x. and my issue of Grails 4..x

Comment: `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter` shouldn't exist in Grails 4.x.  What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown, I added codes into the question, I think you'll get the issue if you see the codes.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I added an answer.  This is unrelated and I know you didn't ask about this, but I expect you are going to have problems with `def r = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceTagLib')`.  I don't expect that to work in Grails 4.

Comment: The `groovy-dateutil` dependency that you show doesn't really have anything to do with `GrailsPageFilter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter`  and `GrailsPageFilter.GSP_SITEMESH_PAGE` you could use `import org.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutView` and `GrailsLayoutView.GSP_SITEMESH_PAGE`.